# want to stream mp4 using Gstreamer by python binding

Tags: rtsp

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, GstRtspServer

loop = GObject.MainLoop()
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)


class RTSP_Server:
       def __init__(self): # 初期化を実行
           self.server = GstRtspServer.RTSPServer()
           self.address = 'localhost' # アドレスを指定
           self.port = '8554'  # ポートを指定
           #self.launch_description = '( playbin uri=file:///mnt\\c\\users\\user\\videos\\test.mp4 )'# 再生したい動画のディレクトリを指定
           self.launch_description = '( filesrc location = C:\\users\\user\\videos\\test.mp4 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )'

            # ここから先がいまいち流れがわかってないですがテストプログラム同じようなことをしている
           self.server.set_address(self.address)
           self.server.set_service(self.port)
           self.server.connect("client-connected",self.client_connected) 
           self.factory = GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory.new()#
           self.factory.set_launch(self.launch_description)
           self.factory.set_shared(True)#
           #self.factory.set_transport_mode(GstRtspServer.RTSPTransportMode.PLAY)
           self.mount_points = self.server.get_mount_points()#
           self.mount_points.add_factory("/video", self.factory)#
           self.server.attach(None)   
           print('Stream ready') # サーバー準備完了...？

       def client_connected(self, arg1, arg2):# ここもわからず
           print('Client connected') # クライアントが（何者かが接続したとき出力...？）

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = RTSP_Server()
    loop.run()
```

my code doesn't go well...
maybe,pipeline config makes problem.

https://github.com/tamaggo/gstreamer-examples
I found this code in git, but can't solve my problem.

So, please help me...